# Force YouCompleteMe to show all the tokens

Tags: vim, autocomplete

Let's create a file `x.rb`, type in `some_code` then on the next line `some_code.some` and what I would like is to see `some_code` in completion menu, but it shows only lang specific terms/functions. In reality I'd like YCM to show me all the words from currently opened files with length more then 3 chars. How could I do that?

Comment: Hit `<C-p>` in insert mode; otherwise, use that plugin's issue tracker.

Comment: That's not the question of how to invoke completion. It is about shorter list of completions rather than it is possible to build.

Comment: And that's not the place to ask for such things. If it's not in the plugin's documentation use their issue tracker.